# Poor performance in animated Flutter widget

Tags: android, performance, flutter, animation

I am creating a game in Flutter that is mostly about dices. To make the background of the main menu interesting and dynamic i added a few blurred animated dices. I also use these animated dices elsewhere in the game. Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

I started off using Flare as an animation library, but the performance was very bad. (using [this](https://rive.app/a/fedejaure/files/flare/dice6/preview) animation).

After that I recreated the animation as a Flutter widget. However the performance is still very poor. On a OnePlus 3 I am getting somewhere around 30-40 fps and on a Galaxy s20 (in 120hz mode) somewhere around 50-60fps. Underneath are the frame rendering times for the OnePlus. Offcourse I am testing in Profile mode. Mainly the Raster thread is doing a lot of work here.

[image: OnePlus 3 Frame rendering times]

[Here is a github repository with the code.](https://github.com/bart1998/Flutter-Dice-Performance) This is a minimalistic version to reproduce the performance problem.

As far as i can see there are no unnecessary rebuilds. The only thing that is rebuild very often is the SlideTransition ([This line](https://github.com/bart1998/Flutter-Dice-Performance/blob/ffcb092675eb53181190cdb42209992bc1cce3aa/lib/DiceStripped.dart#L114)) for the dots.

[image: Widget rebuild statistics]

What can i do to improve the performance? Or what can i try to profile it. I have noticed that removing the Transform.rotate ([this line](https://github.com/bart1998/Flutter-Dice-Performance/blob/ffcb092675eb53181190cdb42209992bc1cce3aa/lib/DiceStripped.dart#L20)) helps, but it does not solve the problem completely.

I am using Flutter 1.20.2 and Dart 2.9.1 in Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: did you notice the poor performance on an emulator or on an actual phone? I have noticed animations that are really laggy in an emulator look fine when the app is compiled and running on a physical device.

Comment: I have tested it on a Galaxy s20 and a OnePlus 3. Both had laggy animations.